# Multi-threaded Context initialization with spring?

Tags: multithreading, spring, initialization, applicationcontext

I have a traditional 3-tier application with spring. One of my repositories needs > 3 minutes for initialization so I thought about some multi-threaded approach in order to speed up the whole process - I think most service and controllers in my dependency tree can already be started so only a few must wait for the last repository to come up.

Is there any best practice approach?

Comment: Which version of Spring? 3.0.x makes this stuff considerably easier.

Comment: yes, I use 3.0.x - so any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Spring's Executor abstraction. And if you are within a app server then I suggest you use application server's work-manager (spring supports it). For e.g. WebSphere app server and Weblogic both support registering the workmanagers in JNDI. You can then pass the jndi name to spring. [Task Executors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: We currently use Tomcat - does it also support such stuff?

Comment: I do not think tomcat supports the work manager. But in tomcat you are good with using other executors provided by spring: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: I see only examples for annotating methods, not for the actual initialization. Do I need custom code for handling the concurrent context initialization?

Comment: May be. it depends on your use case. Identify which beans are taking longer to initialize and try to initialize in async. Go through section "The @Async Annotation" from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html